# onMessageReceived not called on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Please note that there are NO basic issues with the client code like service registration or token issuance issue.

I am using the FCM REST API to send messaged from my app server. The requirement is to show a dialog when the push messages comes and app is in foreground or if the app is in background, just display a notification.

When I use the simple notification payload, everything works fine as expected. But as soon as my message contains a data payload too (in addition to the notification payload), none of the callbacks on my app gets called irrespective of whether the app is in foreground or background.

From documentation, it sounds like message with both kind of payloads should still work - [FireBase Android doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive).

To summarise this works -

```
{  
   "to":"verylongtoken",
   "token":"verylongtoken",
   "notification":{  
      "title":"title",
      "body":"body"
   },
   "priority":"high"
}
```

But this does not -

```
{  
   "to":"verylongtoken",
   "token":"verylongtoken",
   "notification":{  
      "title":"title",
      "body":"body"
   },
   "data":{  
      "message_type":"1"
   },
   "priority":"high"
}
```

Sounds really silly, but what am i missing ?

Comment: change "notification" name to any other name then try

Comment: the messages via firebase-admin are firing properly for both cases

Comment: @Rohit I think I forgot to mention that previously I was sending only the data payload and it was working fine. It is only when the message has both, it does not work. Changing 'notification' to some other name as such will defeat the purpose

Comment: @HovanesMosoyan You mean from firebase composer ?

Comment: change name will work for your all cases, just try once,

Comment: @Rohit I will do it. But can you point me to any documentation which suggests this. Below is a payload example from firebase documentation - {
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    },
    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}

Comment: perhaps yes ) sorry what do you use on the server side ? from where do you send messages?

Comment: in general if the app is in the foreground we should catch the onMessageReceived event and show the notification from the app ), the android doesn't show notification itself when the payload contains DATA KEY

Comment: @h In my case 'onMessageReceived' is not getting triggered.

Comment: have you declared the FirebaseMessagingService in your manifest ? like: 

<service android:name=".YourFirebaseMessagingService">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
     </intent-filter>
 </service>

Comment: As per Documentation notification tag will work if you need system generated notification, on that click you will not able to do any work, it will work with default android icon also, so as per my suggestion there is no need of notification tag in your case, thank you